# Smallest left bounded approximate identity in $L_1(G)\ast\mu$

Tags: harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, and $\mu\in M(G)$ be an idempotent measure. If $(e_\alpha)$ is a standard approximate identity of $L_1(G)$, then $(e_\alpha\ast\mu)$ is a left approximate identity of $L_1(G)\ast\mu$ of the size at most $\Vert\mu\Vert$.

What is the smallest left bounded approximate identity in $L_1(G)\ast\mu$?